# Let p be prime and Fpm denote the field with pm elements. Let k,n be in N.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

I am just trying to solve the first part

[image: I am just trying to solve the first part]

I think I understand how to attempt this problem using a specific p, k, and n, my steps are as follows:

We know that the field $\mathbb F_{p^m}$ = the roots of $x^{p^m} - x$
and for any $a \in \mathbb F_{p^m}$, $a^{p^m} - a = 0$

Using p=2, k=2, and n=4,

We must prove that $x^4 - x \subseteq x^{16} - x$

By dividing $x^4 - x$ into $x^{16} - x$ we get the quotient $(x^{12} + x^9 + x^6 + x^3 + 1) = q(x)$ with no remainder.

Then, we can rewrite

$f(x) = (x^{16} - x) = (x^4 - x)(q(x))$

Substituting for a, where we say for any $a \in \mathbb F_{p^m}, a^{p^m} - a = 0,$ so $(a^4 - a) = 0.$

$f(a) = (a^{16} - a) = (a^4 - a)(q(a)) = 0$

so $a$ is a root of $\mathbb F_4$ and $\mathbb F_{16}$ which means $\mathbb F_4 \subseteq \mathbb F_{16}$

At this point I am unsure of to translate this to an arbitrary p prime, k, and n. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$k|n \Rightarrow p^k-1 | p^n-1 \Rightarrow x^{p^k-1}-1 | x^{p^n-1}-1\Rightarrow x^{p^k}-x | x^{p^n}-x$.

**Edit**

Since $x^{p^k}-x | x^{p^n}-x$. Then
$$x^{p^n}-x=(x^{p^k}-x)q(x)$$

Therefore $(a^{p^k}-a)=0 \Rightarrow (a^{p^n}-a)=0$

Comment: Thanks for the response, would you be able to explain this a little more?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this definitely clears most everything up. The only question I have left is how do you know that $p^k - 1 | p^n -1$? and then how does that imply $x^{p^k -1} - 1 | x^{p^n -1} - 1$? Is this given in a theorem or did you construct that yourself?

Comment: If $k|n$ then $n=tk$ for some integer $t$, we can easily check that $p^n-1=(p^k-1)(p^{k(t-1)}+p^{k(t-2)}+...+1)$. Similary , $p^n-1=(p^k-1)t_2$ then $x^{p^n-1}-1=(x^{p^k-1}-1)(x^{(p^k-1)(t_2-1)}+x^{(p^k-1)(t_2-2)}+...+1$. your welcome.